# Creating database in PostgreSQL following Django installation

Tags: python, django, postgresql, tumbleweed

Forgive me my indolence, but I was following Django installation based on this manual https://idroot.us/install-django-opensuse/ up until to the point where you need to create new database using `createdb mydatabase`. I am using OpenSuse Tumbleweed Release 20240320 and I have tried this in Python virtual environment.

Now, It is giving an obvious error when using `createdb mydatabase`:

"Connection to server on socket "/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory.
Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?"

So I have checked the following:

1. ps -ef | grep postgres

It gives me this:

```
root     12831 27003  0 11:18 pts/0    00:00:02 sudo su - postgres
root     12833 12831  0 11:18 pts/1    00:00:00 sudo su - postgres
root     12834 12833  0 11:18 pts/1    00:00:00 su - postgres
postgres 12835 12834  0 11:18 pts/1    00:00:00 -bash
postgres 12956 12835  0 11:21 pts/1    00:00:02 yes
root     13133 12835  0 11:24 pts/1    00:00:00 sudo su - postgres
root     13135 13133  0 11:24 pts/2    00:00:00 sudo su - postgres
root     13136 13135  0 11:24 pts/2    00:00:00 su - postgres
postgres 13137 13136  0 11:24 pts/2    00:00:00 -bash
postgres 14851 13137 99 11:59 pts/2    00:00:00 ps -ef
postgres 14852 13137  0 11:59 pts/2    00:00:00 grep --color=auto postgres
```

2. cat /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432 No such a file or directory
3. When I try psql -U postgres It gives me the same error
4. When I check systemctl status postgresql It gives me this:

```
     postgresql.service - PostgreSQL database server
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; disabled; preset: disabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
```

Postgres is installed, I am postgres user itself, but obviously I cannot create any DB since "Connection to server on socket "/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed.

Can you please point out the directions for me, so I can make the socket running on Tumbleweed and create new DB?

Thanks

Comment: You need to start the Postgres service that will create the socket and also listen on port 5432.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could:

```bash
sudo -i
```

then

```bash
systemctl enable postgresql
```

then

```bash
systemctl start postgresql
```